# Send order to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Parent = ({list}) => {

   const closeAll = () => {
   // What should be in here?
   }

   return (
       <>
        <button onClick={() => closeAll()}>Close All</button>
        {list.map(item => <Accordion item={item}/>)}
       </>
   )
     
}


const Accordion = ({item}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
      <div onClick={() => setOpen(o => !o)}>
          <p>item.name</p>
          {open && <p>item.detail</p>
      </div>   
  )
}
```

Basically, as above, there is the `Accordion` components and a parent component that hosts all of them. Each `Accordion` component has a state called `open`. I want to change state of each child from parent component. How can I send an order to a child component to change its state?

Comment: It's not really a component's place to tell other components "what to do". You can move all the open states into the parent component and the parent maintains the "source of truth" ([Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)) and explicitly passes an `open` prop to each child. This is the preferred method. ***If you must*** leave the open state in each child then you can use a React ref and expose out an imperative close handler that a parent component can invoke. Which sounds more like something you want to try/implement?

Comment: Here's the documentation for the first thing Drew mentioned: ["lifting state up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I won't use the ref idea now (it's not mandatory to keep the state in the child.) but thanks for the idea. I didn't know it could be used like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lift your state up into `Parent`.

- `closeAll` can just map over the list and set all the `open` properties to `false`.
- Have a `handleClick` callback that you pass down to `Accordion` which sets the state of the clicked item's `open` property to the inverse in `Parent`
- Take a look at the [react docs for lifting state up.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const data = [
  {
    detail: "foo",
    name: "bar"
  },
  {
    detail: "foo1",
    name: "bar1"
  }
];

const Parent = ({ defaultList = data }) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(
    defaultList.map((i) => ({
      ...i,
      open: false
    }))
  );

  const closeAll = () => {
    setList(
      list.map((i) => ({
        ...i,
        open: false
      }))
    );
  };

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    const newList = [...list];
    newList[i].open = !list[i].open;

    setList(newList);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => closeAll()}>Close All</button>
      {list.map((item, i) => (
        <Accordion item={item} handleClick={() => handleClick(i)} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Accordion = ({ item, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</button>
      {item.open && <p>{item.detail}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

[image: Edit fervent-allen-9wlmh]

---

If you are unable to lift your state there is an alternative approach using react refs.

Create ref (initially an empty array) that each `Accordion` will push its own close state setting function into when it first renders.

In `Parent`, loop over the the array of close state settings functions inside the ref and execute each.

```
const Parent = ({ list = data }) => {
  const myRef = useRef([]);

  const closeAll = () => {
    myRef.current.forEach((c) => c());
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => closeAll()}>Close All</button>
      {list.map((item, i) => (
        <Accordion item={item} myRef={myRef} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Accordion = ({ item, myRef }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.push(() => setOpen(false));
  }, [myRef]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setOpen((o) => !o)}>{item.name}</button>
      {open && <p>{item.detail}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

[image: Edit close from above using refs]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try creating a state variable inside the parent and passing it as a prop to the child to control the behavior of the child.

```
const Parent = ({ list }) => {
  const [masterOpen, setMasterOpen] = useState(true);
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setMasterOpen(false)}>Close All</button>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <Accordion item={item} parentOpen={masterOpen} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Accordion = ({ item, parentOpen }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  if (!parentOpen) {
    setOpen(false);
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setOpen((o) => !o)}>
      <p>{item.name}</p>
      {open && <p>item.detail</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an internal state for the component is not recommended, at least from my point of view for what you are doing.

you can control the open state of each list item from its properties like the example here:

```js
const Parent = ({ list }) => {
    const [isAllClosed, setIsAllClosed] = useState(false);

    const closeAll = () => {
        setIsAllClosed(true)
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={closeAll}>Close All</button>
            {list.map((item) => (
                item.open = isAllClosed != null ? (!isAllClosed) : true;
                <Accordion item={item} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

const Accordion = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => console.log('item clicked')}>
            <p>item.name</p>
            {item.open ? <p>item.detail</p> : null}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I also replaced you short circuit evaluation `open && <p>item.detail</p>` to a ternary. The reason for that is that you will get a string `false` being printed if not true, does it make sense?

You will need somehow control the state of the whole list whether an item is open or not from whoever is using the parent.

But avoid using internal state when you can.